# Reference last value returned by Clojure REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I'm at the Clojure REPL and I enter a value

```
user=> [:a :b :c]
[:a :b :c]
```

How can I refer to that value in a later expression?

Answer (score 5):

- `*1` for the last result
- `*2` for the one before `*1`
- and finally `*3` (can't go back further)

For example:

```
user=> [:a :b :c]
[:a :b :c]
user=> (count *1)
3
```

See https://clojure.org/guides/repl/data_visualization_at_the_repl#_accessing_recent_results_1_2_3

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
(clojure.pprint/pp)
```

which is the same as

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint *1)
```